# Difficulty with implements requery in android java project

Tags: java, android, orm, dao

Im working in a new project android and wanna know one bit more of requery ORM and I have some difficult in search in web for this library.

I Having a difficulty in implements the usage...a problem give me the message **"Ambiguous method call"** when I use the **SELECT QUERY** method utilising my **OrderEntity** in scope of following method:

```
@override
public @nonnull List getAllOrders() {


     return mDataStore.select(OrderEntity.class)
       .get()
       .toList();

}
```

and the interface Order...

```
@entity
public interface Order extends Persistable{

       @Key
       @Generated
       int getId();

       @Index(value = "name")
       String getName();

       @OneToMany(mappedBy = "owner", cascade = {CascadeAction.DELETE, 
       CascadeAction.SAVE})
       List<product> getProductList();

}
```

If anyone can help me I aprecciate!

Thanks!